# Composition of two permutations, expressed in cycle notation

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

I'm wondering if I did the problem correctly.

$[(1 2 3) (45)] \circ [(3 4)(1 2)]$

So, I started with (1

and $1 \to 2 \to 3$

then it becomes (1 3

and I did 3; $3 \to 4 \to 5$

then it becomes (1 3 5

now I did 5; $5 \to 4$

then it becomes (1 3 5 4

now to check 4; $4 \to 3 \to 1$ and 1 is being repeated.

the composition of two permutation is (1 3 5 4)

So, I am wondering if it is correctly done.

Comment: This looks correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct.  You applied the permutation on the right and then the one on the left.

You should be aware, however, that, when combining permutations,

some authors apply the one on the left first and then the one on the right.

It's a good idea to specify which convention is being followed.

Comment: if I did the other way around, It should give you the same answer, right?

Comment: No!  That's my point.  You should try it.  You could leave a comment here if you want me to check your answer.  We say that composition of permutations is *not* generally commutative

Comment: I will try it and give you another comment ;)